# Laravel: Input old for date field

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to have my date field remember my old input

Is there any way i can do this?

**Here's my code**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="date1">Date From: </label>
        <input id="date1" name="date1" type="date"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" class="form-control">

    </div>  


<div class="form-group">
        <label for="date2">Date To: </label>
        <input id="date2" name="date2" type="date"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" class="form-control">

    </div>
```

Please Help. Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have a default but also remember the user provided input in case of any error you could do something like this:

`<input type="date" name="date2" value="{{ old('date2', date('Y-m-d')) }}">`

Then in your controller when you redirect back make sure to call the `->withInput()`method.

Comment: You are probably using Laravel 4 so just replace that function with the facade: `Request::old('date2', date('Y-m-d') )`

Comment: can ->withInput() method  be used in return View::make?
because im calling my method as 'post' method :/

Comment: So what should happen is you first validate the user input to make sure the data is in the correct format and what not.

Then if that validation fails you want to return to the form and inform the user about the validation erros and refill the form inputs again.

`$input = Input::all();
$validator = Validator::make($input, array('email' => 'required|email'));
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
} 
else
{
 return View::make('some.view')->with('success', 'Your data was saved to storage!');
}`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to redirect from your controller "With inputs" something like this:

```
return redirect('some/form/route')->withInput();
```

Then in your template:

```
  Request::old('date_field')
```

Or in a blade template:

```
  {{ old('date_field') }}
```

More detail in the "[Old Input](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#old-input)" section in L5 docs